# ¿Cómo ejecutar comandos cql y medir sus tiempos de ejecución?

Tags: cassandra

Quirero ejecutar un fichero cualquiera que sea su tipo que me permitiria hacer operaciones sobre una base de datos Cassandra. Es por decir hacer una consulta, una actualización, eliminación, una inserción, Realizar cada tipo de operación 10 veces y calcule el tiempo promedio ejecución para cada uno.

```
INSERT INTO k1.tabla (code, url, creator, created_t, created_datetime, ...) 
   VALUES (6661, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ...);
```

Entonces puedo hacer un fichero con 10 INSERT, 10 UPDATE, 10 DELETE y 10 SELECT.

Sé que puedo utilisar [el tracing](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2)

Pero como por ejemple puedo ejecutar y mantener el tiempo de ejecución para nalysarlo despues ?

```
cqlsh> tracing on;
```

---

No sé si esta necesario escribir todas las columnas en el INSERT cuando necesite escribir una dato.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás sea de utilidad la herramienta cassandra-stress tool, que viene distribuida con el propio Cassandra (sus resultados serán bastante fiables).

Viene dentro de la carpeta tools, y su uso es bastante sencillo.

Un par de ejemplos simples.

Este realiza 50000 escrituras:

```
cassandra-stress write n=50000 no-warmup -rate threads=1
```

Este ejecuta 50000 lecturas:

```
cassandra-stress read n=50000 no-warmup -rate threads=1
```

Este usa el fichero de ejemplo proporcionado por cassandra para una prueba más completa:

```
cassandra-stress user ops\(insert=2,simple1=1\) profile=cqlstress-example.yaml n=50000 no-warmup -rate threads=1
```